# CasperJS: evaluate() returns null value

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Giving the following example, why is `categoryId` `null` ?

```
var scripts = this.evaluate(function() {
    var raScripts = "A lengthy script";

    return raScripts;
});

var categoryId = this.evaluate(function() {
    var text = 'more text';
    var lengthyScript = scripts + ' ' + text;

    return lengthyScript;
});

this.echo('Status: ' + categoryId);
// categoryId is null
```

Comment: The variable `scripts` is defined outside of the page context, but used inside.

Comment: And how can I make use of the `raScripts` variabile outside of the `this.evaluate` function?

Comment: You already did that by returning it from the `evaluate` callback. The value of `raScripts` is equal to the value of `scripts` (if the value was a primitive object without cyclic references). You just have to pass the value of `script` back into the page context for the next "computation" inside of the page context.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because your `scripts` variable is not defined in the browser environment (it is only defined in your Casper environment). Indeed, when you use `evaluate`, the context is the DOM, not the Casper instance.

This will return `null`:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var tag = 'h1'; // This is our global variable...

casper.start('http://example.com/');

casper.waitForSelector('body', function () {
  this.echo(this.evaluate(function () {
    return document.querySelector(tag).textContent; // Oops!
  }));
});

casper.run();
```

But if we inject our variable in the context of `evaluate`, we get the expected result (which is "Example Domain"):

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://example.com/');

casper.waitForSelector('body', function () {
  this.echo(this.evaluate(function (tag) {
    return document.querySelector(tag).textContent;
  }, 'h1'));
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I really can't wrap my head around your example. The `scripts` variable does return "A lengthy script".
My problem is with the `categoryId` variable. It returns `null` instead of 'A lengthy script more text', even though is built on the same logic as `scripts` variable.